# MongoDB created collection shows in NodeJS but not in CLI?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a capped collection in MongoDB using NodeJS driver.

```
db.createCollection(req.body.name,options,function onCreateCollection(mongoErr,mongoCollection){
    if(mongoErr){
            ... 
    }else{
            console.log( mongoCollection.collectionName );
            ...
    }
});
```

The collection name prints on the console but `show collections` does not list it. I tried a hyphenated name `this-is-a-collection`.

Why is that?
Also, what are the limitations in naming a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code doesn't work. But I just tried to create a collection with the hyphenated name `this-is-a-collection` with this simple script, it worked.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    db.createCollection('this-is-a-collection', { capped : true, size : 10000 } ,function onCreateCollection(err,mongoCollection){
       if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(mongoCollection.collectionName);
        }

        db.close();
    });
});
```

And in the CLI :

```
MBP:mongo sapher$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: test
....
> use db
switched to db db
> show collections
system.indexes
this-is-a-collection
```

You can follow this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions) to get more info on MongoDB naming restrictions.

For naming convention, I personnaly use snake case like `remote_users`. I think this is the most elegant way to name a collection. Naming isn't that important as long as you stay consistent.

Comment: yeah I get a successful response, too. Just that it doesnt turn up in the CLI.

Comment: Weird It's working for me. I just edit my answer with the CLI output.

Comment: Try making it a capped collection and see if it makes a difference :/

Comment: I just edit my code with the missing capped option I forget to add. It's working ^^. Maybe you forget to add the mandatory size option?

Comment: I just tried the `1.4.9` .. it's working lol. Maybe it's another issue, maybe you should add more code.

Comment: Check my answer. I mixed up size and max.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, on older version of the driver `1.4.x`, creating a capped collection without specifying the `size` option doesn't result in an error. **It even returns a success response**. On the newer version, `2.0.x`, it does result in an error.

For a capped collection, `size` is needed while `max` is optional. The [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#createCollection) are slightly ambiguous as they do not state that you need a `size` to create a capped collection.

Comment: I'm glad you finally resolve your issue. I think you were one of the first to bump into this issue ^^. Finally my answer didn't solve your question.

Comment: @Sapher +1 me then :p

Comment: @Sapher It did. I would never have looked at `size` option had it not been for you. :)